# What is the location in which I can find Couchbase lite location in IOS 8.3?

Tags: ios, couchbase, couchbase-lite

Need to install a pre-built couches lite database in my IOS application, for that I need to locate the database's .cblite file.

When I go to `[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]` . I cannot find anything.

Comment: You will likely need to add it to the resources to copy in XCode

Comment: Thanks @ThomasKilian, but i am not able to locate  database's .cblite file in the first place i.e. the location where the database is created.

Answer (score 1):

You can use http://simpholders.com/ to locate the application folder in a simulator running the app with Couchbase Lite.

The `cblite` file and folder to store the attachments are in the folder returned by SimPholders in `Library/Application Support/CouchbaseLite`.

Once you have the canned database, see this [documentation guide](http://developer.couchbase.com/mobile/develop/guides/couchbase-lite/native-api/database/index.html#installing-pre-built) to use it as a resource in your app and to set it up with the `replaceDatabaseNamed:withDatabaseFile:withAttachments:error:` method.